# Dynamic routing issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am a little confused with dynamic routing as I am new to NextJS. I want it to be in such a way that if someone clicks on the title of my page, it takes them to a new page which consists the same title and body. What changes can I make in order to achieve this? I checked out many resources but they are either from a to b and the data is hardcoded.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import Link from 'next/link';


class Abc extends React.Component{
    state = {
        title: '',
        body: '',
        posts: []
    };

    componentDidMount=()=>{
        this.getBlogPost();
    };



displayBody=(posts: Array<any>)=>{
 if(!posts.length)
 return null;
 return posts.map((post,index)=>(
<div key={index}>

 <Link href={`/post?title=${this.state.title}`} ><a> 
 {post.title}</a></Link>
    <h2>{post.title}</h2>
    <p>{post.body}</p>

</div>
 ));

};
    render() {
        console.log('state', this.state);
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Welcome to my app</h2>

            <div className="blog">

                {this.displayBody(this.state.posts)}
            </div>


            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Abc
```

Answer (score 0):

> if someone clicks on the title of my post, it takes them to a new page
>   which consists the same title and body

Do you mean the title and body is being fetched from MongoDB based on parameter clicked by user?

If yes, since you are using ExpressJS, you can take a look on their example on Github:

```
server.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/posts', { id: req.params.id })
})
```

There is an API `/posts/:id` which basically fulfil what do you want to achieve. The idea is to get unique parameter from user's request, then forward this parameter to your specific page, and call API to fetch to MongoDB based on user's parameter.

> Update Answer

This is what `pages/posts` look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class extends Component {
  static getInitialProps({ query: { id, title, body } }) {
    return { postId: id, title, body }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>My blog post #{this.props.postId}</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What you need to do is add `getInitialProps` function that retrieve the id from query sent by your server.

> Second Update Answer

Then you can use `next/link` object url like below:

```
<Link href={{ pathname: `/post?title=${this.state.title}`, query: { title: this.state.title, body: this.state.body } }}>
    <a>{post.title}</a>
</Link>
```

If the example is not working, you need to combine it with `withRouter` from `next/router` to access your query from Router object.

Complete example: [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/custom-server-express/server.js)

Comment: I have added my server file and I am able to both get and post my requests. I have added my server code as well. Currently I only have two files for my project. Index.ts and server.ts. Could u please check because using "Link href" I could create a link to my title but nothing appears within it (index file) @Darryl RN

Comment: your server file already correct to have API that listen to get `/api` and post `/api/save`. Now, what you need to do is add one more API that listen to get `/[your_preference_path]/[unique_id]` like the example of my answer.

Comment: That's exactly where my problem, how do I create that API? 
server.get('/posts/:id', (req, res) => {. 
  return app.render(req, res, '/posts', { id: req.params.id })
})
I have created this as well in my server.js and created a pages file in there. What do I mention in the pages file (API) to achieve this? Could u post a code snippet to help me with this? @ Darryl RN

Comment: What about the body and title? I tried adding {this.props.body} and {this.props.title} but it only works to display the id but not the title and body associated with the ID  @Darryl RN

Comment: you won't send the title and body via `next/router` query don't you?
the reason why you have API caller in your page is to fetch title and body based on ID you get from user request's query.

Comment: @ Darryl RN , the id, body, title and date are within my database. I am calling them via a get request and rendering the title of my post but as soon as someone clicks on the title it should be able to see the title and the post. With the code provided by you I could only view the Id on my page, but I wish to even view the post and body which is coming from my database for that particular ID.  How can I achieve this? Could u please update your code?

Comment: The body that is added by you in your code is hardcoded and I want the body and title just like the Id to come from my database. Right now with your code I am only able to display ID when someone clicks on the title of my post but unable to view the post and body associated with that ID @ Darryl RN

Comment: you can take a look on my example now

Comment: Your second answer did not work for me, did I have to make any changes to my "/pages" file in order to get the second code working? @Darryl RN

Comment: have you tried my suggestion to use `withRouter`? read doc here https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#withrouter.

Comment: I did check it, but I am not understanding what kind of alterations need to be made thats why I have posted this query. With router seems to be very similar to Link. What changes do I have to make exactly? @ Darryl RN

Comment: Please, if you know how to do it using withRouter please update the code. @Darryl RN